# JQuery problems with setting variables in if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to set a variable to 0 if an item attribute is equal a specific string, else set the variable to 1, but I can't get it to work.

My code is like this in my javascript function:

```
    var variable;
    if ($(this).attr("attribute", "string"))
        variable=0;
    else
        variable=1;
```

For some reason, the variable always get set to 0, even if the item attribute isn't equal the specific string.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this instead:

```
var variable;
if ($(this).attr("attribute") == "string")
    variable=0;
else
    variable=1;
```

`$(this).attr("attribute", "string")` sets the attribute `attribute` to `string`, it doesn't test if `attribute` equals `string`.

See the [`attr(attributeName,value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
var variable;
if ($(this).attr("attribute") == "string")
    variable=0;
else
    variable=1;
```

This compares the value of attribute `"attribute"` to the value `"string"`. What you're doing at the moment is setting the value of attribute `"attribute"` to the value `"string"`. I suspect this function will return a "truthy" value hence `variable` always being set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the string in your if

```
if( $(this).attr("attribute", "string") ){
```

You need to read it and compatre

```
if( $(this).attr("attribute") === "string") ){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this[attribute="string"])`.